# Does this sequence converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

We consider some sequence $(f^{(k)})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\subset L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that
$f^{(k)}\to f$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Further assume there is some $R>0$ so that $\text{supp}(f^{(k)}),\text{supp}(f)\subset B_R(0)$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Now consider
$$f_n^{(k)}=f^{(k)}\ast \psi_{\varepsilon_n},$$
where $\psi_{\varepsilon_n}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon^n}\psi(\frac{x}{\varepsilon_n})$ and $\psi$ is the standard mollifier. Is it true that
$$f_n^{(k)}\to f^{(k)}$$
uniformly (in $k$) in $L^p$?

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: In general I can only say that for fixed $k$ $f_n^{k}\to f^{k}$ as $n\to \infty$. But I honestly have no clue how to show that it is uniform. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: The only way to do it is to get an estimate of $||f_n^{(k)}-f^{(k)}||_{L^p}$, because of course what you ask cannot hold if you replace $f_n^{(k)}$ with any $x_{i,j}$ of an arbitrary metric space. I suggest you write down the proof of $f_n$ going to $f$ in $L^p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different (and kind of high level) approach. Working through the standard proof of convergence of mollification seems to be hard. One would need a uniformity for the density argument.

Let me denote by $T_n$ the mollification associated with $\epsilon_n$.
We have $T_ny \to y$ in $L^p$ for all $y\in L^p$ and $f_k \to f$ in $L^p$. Moreover, $\|T_n\|_{\mathcal L(L^p,L^p)}\le 1$ by standard estimates.

Now
$$ 
T_nf_k - f_k = T_n(f_k-f)  + (T_nf-f) + (f_k-f).
$$
Due to $\|T_n\|\le 1$ the first and third term converge to zero for $k\to\infty$ uniformly in $n$. The middle one converges to zero for $n\to \infty$: Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there is $K$ such that $\|f_k-f\|<\epsilon/3$ for all $k>K$. In addition, there is $N$ such that $\|T_nf-f\|<\epsilon/3$ and $\|T_nf_k-f_k\|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$ and all $k=1\dots K$. Hence $\|T_nf_k-f_k\|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$ and all $k$.

Comment: That's a nice idea. I have to admit that I'm still not quite sure why this is now true for all $k$. For any $\varepsilon>0$ you can find $K$ so that $\|f_k-f\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ for all $k\geq K$. Then $T_nf_k-f_k$ is also not uniformly converging in $k$?

Comment: For $k<K$ these are finitely many converging sequences. So these are uniformly converging.

Comment: You're right thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\delta>0$. Due to the density of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^3)$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$ there is $(f_k)_{\delta}\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^3)$ so that
$$ \|f_k-(f_k)_{\delta}\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)}<\frac{\delta}{3}.$$ Moreover we know that $\text{supp}(f_k),\text{supp}((f_k)_{\delta})\subset \overline{B_{\tilde{R}(0)}}$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and for some $\tilde{R}>0$ big enough. Further for any $x\in B_R(0)$
$$|(f_k)_{\delta}(x)-((f_k)_{\delta})_{\varepsilon}(x)|\leq \int_{B_R(0)}\psi_{\varepsilon}(x-y)|(f_k)_{\delta}(x)-(f_k)_{\delta}(y)|dy\\
\leq \sup_{x\in B_R(0),y\in B_{\varepsilon}(x)}|(f_k)_{\delta}(x)-(f_k)_{\delta}(y)|<\frac{\delta}{3}$$
for fixed $k$. And further
$$\|(f_k)_{\varepsilon}-((f_k)_{\delta})_{\varepsilon}\|_{L^p}=\|(f_k)-((f_k)_{\delta})\|_{L^p}<\frac{\delta}{3}.$$
Then by triangle inequality we have
$$\|f_k-(f_k)_{\varepsilon}\|_{L^p}\leq \|f_k-(f_k)_{\delta}\|_{L^p}+\|(f_k)_{\delta}-((f_k)_{\delta})_{\varepsilon}\|_{L^p}+\|((f_k)_{\delta})_{\varepsilon}-(f_k)_{\varepsilon}\|_{L^p}.$$
In the first step I first fix $f_k$ and then choose $\delta$ so it is dependent on $k$. In the second step the same again. And for the third estimate I use the first one so it also depends on $k$. How can I get the independence of $k$ now?